# Multiple devices connections with netmiko

Tags: python, connection, netmiko

I'm having a problem that I can't solve.

i Have this script:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

cisco_ios = []

sandbox_cisco = {
    "device_type":"cisco_ios",
    "host":"sandbox-iosxe-latest-1.cisco.com",
    "port":"22",
    "username":"developer",
    "password":"C1sco12345"
    }
cisco_ios.append(sandbox_cisco)

sandbox_cisco_2 = {
    "device_type":"cisco_ios",
    "host":"sandbox-iosxr-1.cisco.com",
    "port":"22",
    "username":"admin",
    "password":"C1sco12345"
    }
cisco_ios.append(sandbox_cisco_2)


command = "show interfaces description"

def get_interface(command,**kwargs):

    for ne in kwargs:
        net_connect = ConnectHandler(**ne)
        comando = net_connect.send_command(command)
        net_connect.disconnect()
        print(comando)

get_interface(command,cisco_ios) #line 35
```

and it gives me the following error:

```
 line 35, in <module>
    get_interface(command,cisco_ios)
TypeError: get_interface() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

if i add "**" in the line 35 it returns the following error:

```
line 35, in <module>
    get_interface(command, **cisco_ios)
TypeError: __main__.get_interface() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list
```

can you help me? i don't know what i doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

`cisco_ios` is a list so you should do something like this:

```py
def get_interface(command, devices):

    for ne in devices:
        net_connect = ConnectHandler(**ne)
        comando = net_connect.send_command(command)
        net_connect.disconnect()
        print(comando)
```

For your information. `kwargs` is used for passing multible keyword arguments to a function